# Rotate Image from URI without Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, image

I have found solutions how to rotate pictures if you apply to URI to a bitmap and rotate it, but I work with really big pictures which need to keep their resolution but if I try to work with bitmaps and apply those I get OutofMemory errors pretty soon.

So is there a way to do it without bitmaps or am I stuck?

Comment: Unless you find something that uses the NDK, I don't think you have an option other than `Bitmap` and a `Matrix`. Note that if your objective is to show the image rotated, you could rotate the `ImageView` instead of rotating the image.

Comment: If not bitmaps then what do you consider to be pictures?

Comment: `if you apply to URI to a bitmap ` ????

Comment: @CommonsWare I will try this approach again. My problem is that some images that should be horizontal according to Exif data are shown vertically.

Comment: @greenapps I currently use .setImageURI

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to display a rotated image in an `ImageView`, try using its `rotation` attribute.

As an example, if you want to display an image upside down to a user, download the image and set it on the `ImageView`. The `ImageView` could be something like this.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_upsidedown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="180"/>
```

The resulting image would be upside down.